# Special Sequence Replace in String in C#

Tags: c#, .net, string, replace

I have a string like below

```
Testing\u001cTesting Testing Testing\u001cTesting
```

When I try to send this response in `Http.Response`, I got like (square box) in Postman.

I want to replace `\u001c` with `\u{001c}`.

I tried with following,

- `myText.Replace("\u001c", @"\\u{001c}");` --- it getting replace like this `\\\\u{001c}`
- `myText.Replace("\u001c", @"u{001c}");` --- it getting replace like this `u{001c}`
- `myText.Replace("\u001c", @"\u{001c}");` --- it getting replace like this `\\u{001c}`
- `myText.Replace("u001c", @"u{001c}");` --- it getting replace like this (square box)

Where is my mistake?

Comment: The mistake is probably in how you see the result value: the debugger helpfully shows a string-value as if it were source code - with doubled backslashes. Try the magnifier to show it as real text

Comment: I assume that `\u001c` is a *single* character (a "field separator"), specified by its Unicode codepoint escape sequence (hex 1C, decimal 28) and not six characters starting with an actual backslash? This is not a "printable character" therefore Postman cannot display it

Answer (score 0):

The '\' char is a special character. When you want to include that character in a string you have to use a escaping char which also is '\'.
So if you want to have "c:\a.txt" you need it to write it like "c:\\a.txt".
But this makes handling addresses and URLs hard as they might have lots of '\' in them.
So when you want to use a address you can put @ before string and let the compiler to add escaping char.
In short when you use @"\" the compiler adds a second one.
If you want to replace "\u001c" with "\u{001c}" you have to do as below:

```
myText.Replace("\\u001c", "\\u{001c}");
```